Targeting (and invalidating) triples not targeted by SHACL shapes
If I have a collection of shapes, is there a pure SHACL way to invalidate any triples that are not targeted by those shapes?
e.g.
you receive a graph from someone. It contains a bunch of triples. Some of the subjects , predicates and objects in those triples are targeted by your SHACL shapes.
However, the data provider makes spelling mistakes, or has bad intentions and decided to add a bunch of triples that have nothing to do with the data delivery.
like
data:
ex:bridge1 a ex:Bridge ;
 ex:width "12".

ex:bobby ex:favouriteColor "green".

shape:
ex:bridgeShape a sh:NodeShape ;
sh:targetClass ex:Bridge ;
sh:property [sh:path ed:width ; sh:minCount 1].

my bridge shape will target the bridge instance, and validate it. But since I have no shape about bobby, that data will be considered "valid". For systems that use SHACL shapes for validating/data-ingestion pipelines, this seems like a problem.
For properties (so once you have targetted a node) you can use sh:closed true, but if the node is never targeted explicitly, I don't see a simple way to restrict it. Is there a generic way to express this in SHACL?

One way, although it is not entirely my preferred way because it's not generic, is to require all nodes in the graph to be rdf:type'd and then use sh:in and sh:closed + sh:ignoredProperties shapes to limit the properties and types that those things can be and use.
This has the advantage of being relatively simple to implement - you just need big lists of all the things that you have shapes about. The disadvantage is that if you have ontologies with hundreds or thousands of classes, those lists become very large (readability, potential for spelling mistakes), and I'm not sure about the performance considerations.
That's why a generic SHACL shape that is aware of the shapes graph (and not just the data graph) would be useful. We already have the ability to do comparitive shapes like sh:equals, so SHACL graphs are somewhat self-aware...
Note in the example below, I represent my ontology by ex:targetClass1. It checks only things that are typed as ex:class1, and that they may have a value for ex:pred. Any other subjects that are not of that type should be considered invalid, as they are not targeted by any shapes.
Example:
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

ex:checker a owl:Ontology ;
    sh:declare [
        sh:prefix "ex" ;
        sh:namespace "http://example.com/ns#"^^xsd:anyURI ;
    ] ;
    sh:declare [
        sh:prefix "rdfs" ;
        sh:namespace "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"^^xsd:anyURI ;
    ] ;
    sh:declare [
        sh:prefix "schema" ;
        sh:namespace "http://schema.org/"^^xsd:anyURI ;
    ] ;
    sh:declare [
        sh:prefix "owl" ;
        sh:namespace "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"^^xsd:anyURI ;
    ] ;
    sh:declare [
        sh:prefix "rdf" ;
        sh:namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"^^xsd:anyURI ;
    ] .

ex:targetClass1 a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass ex:class1 ;
    sh:property [sh:path rdf:type ;
                    sh:minCount 1] ;
    sh:property [sh:path ex:pred ;
                    sh:minCount 1] .

ex:TargetAllSubjects a sh:SPARQLTarget ;
        sh:select """
        PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
        PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
        PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
        PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
            SELECT ?this
            WHERE {
                ?this ?pred ?object .
            }
        """ .

ex:TargetAllTypedThings a sh:SPARQLTarget ;
    sh:select """
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
    PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/>
        SELECT ?this
        WHERE {
            ?this rdf:type ?type .
        }
    """ .

ex:EverythingMustBeTyped a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:target ex:TargetAllSubjects ;
    sh:property [sh:path rdf:type ;
                    sh:minCount 1] 
    .

ex:NoNewThings a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:target ex:TargetAllTypedThings ;
    sh:closed true ;
    sh:ignoredProperties (rdf:type ex:pred ) .


ex:OnlyTheseClassesAllowed a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:target ex:TargetAllTypedThings ;
    sh:property [sh:path rdf:type ;
                    sh:in (ex:class1)] ;
.



